Execution failed for AarToClassTransform - Getting failure while publishing Sdk on jitpack
Getting this exception on jitpack :


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform fullauthrfid-7.2.10816.aar to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /home/jitpack/build/app/libs/fullauthrfid-7.2.10816.aar.
         > zip END header not found

I have built an sdk and the sdk is dependent on an .aar package. The build runs successfully and I can generate the .aar file from my project locally without any errors, using this method :
gradle > Tasks > build > build
I have pushed the latest code to github and using jitpack to publish this sdk. But the process fails on jitpack with an exception. I am attaching the logs for reference.
Jitpack logs : https://jitpack.io/com/github/yazanalqasem/iPass2.0CoreAndroidSDK/2.9/build.log
